# How to determine which PHP Handler is set on a server

Tags: wordpress

Is there a PHP command I can execute through a browser that will return which PHP Handler my server is setup to use?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is aimed at [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Interesting question. Do you want to do this on a one-off basis, or programmatically?

Comment: If you want to do this programmatically, you'll need to set up a `phpinfo()` page, and then capture it as a string using `ob_` methods. You can then parse the HTML for the data you want.

Comment: (Don't worry about downvotes here. They are probably because you had already tried `phpinfo` but you didn't mention that in your post. Always explain what you've tried here `:-)`).

Comment: @tammy you can ask for that clarification here - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ DV's are anonymous for a well tested and vetted reasons. You can post a link to your question there, ask about the DV's and ask how to improve. But beware the Meta Effect (additional votes because you're bringing more awareness to your question).

Comment: No, just a link to the question asking how you can improve it.

Answer (score 5):

Create a page with the following -

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Load that into your browser and will show you everything that you need to know about PHP running on your server including all enabled modules. **The handler is listed as "Server API" on that page.**

[DSO on Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/dso.html)

Comment: I did say to load it into a browser @halfer - do I need to say it will not work from the command line?

Comment: Right, I'm using Stack Overflow whilst tired! Apologies, it's fine as it is!

Comment: OK @tammy, that wasn't clear. You didn't see a 'Server API' entry in the info page?

Comment: Apache is typically DSO @tammy

Comment: I understand @tammy. Have you looked at the http.conf to see how it is configured? Why is this such a hot issue for you?

Comment: Have you looked at the httpd.conf file @tammy? However, there is likely a way to configure things without having to change the server handler. I have added the WordPress tag in hops that WP users will gets eyes on this and have a solution. Which plugin did you install?

Comment: Terrific. If you have confirmed DSO by viewing the httpd.conf all you need to do is install another handler on your server and you should be good to go @tammy.

Comment: You cannot, other than what has been pointed out with `phpinfo()`. Some OS's are better at reporting than others. You have to examine the configuration of the server in order to confirm  the handlers.

Answer (score 0):

create a page phpinfo.php with the following content

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Try visting the page, it should display all settings associated with your PHP installation.

Answer (score 0):

On the command line you can you can use

```
/path/to/your/bin/rebuild_phpconf --current
```

You will get a list of available handlers including the current one like this

```
DEFAULT PHP: 5
PHP4 SAPI: none
PHP5 SAPI: suphp
SUEXEC: enabled
RUID2: not installed
```

Comment: What operating systems or distros is that available on? I'm on Ubuntu 13.x, Apache is installed, and I don't seem to have this.

Comment: Looks like the phpinfo() route is the alternative if you don't have command line access. Im not aware of any simple function that gets you the handler data.